# Mootools's tween and periodical comparability

Tags: mootools, tween

I have a tween effect that works fine with a click event but I would like it to work with periodical. Please help! Thanks in advance.

```
// Tween effect
var bounce = function() {
    this.set('tween', {duration: 1500, transition: 'bounce:out'});
    this.tween('right', [900, 40]);
}

// This works fine
$('someID').addEvent('click', bounce);

// These don't work
bounce();
bounce.periodical(10000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach the `bounce()` to the click event then you can use `this` in that function,  but outside that you need to define the "this". You could use bind, or change `this` to your element.

Try this:

```
var bounce = function() {
    var element = $('someID'); // cache it here or outside the function
    element.set('tween', {duration: 1500, transition: 'bounce:out'});
    element.tween('right', [900, 40]);
}

bounce();
bounce.periodical(10000);
```

Comment: @ngungo, happy I could help! If you want you can also click to accept the answer. Cheers